# LINQ to Entities Query When Adding a New Table in DataModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a JoinModel class to join multiple tables courselist, coursesummary under Model folder.  It works fine before. Now I add a table with new year, courselist2019, and added courselist2019 to CourseDateModel.cs. But I got the error message complains "Cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query". I am using Entity Framework 6, code first to generate CourseDataModel.cs file. Below is my code:

CourseDataModel.cs

```
namespace course.Models
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public partial class CourseDataModel : DbContext
{
    public CourseDataModel()
        : base("name=CourseDataModel")
    {
    }


    public virtual DbSet<courselist> courselist { get; set; 
    public virtual DbSet<courselist2019> courselist2019 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<contentsummary> contentsummary { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}
}
```

JoinModel.cs

```
public class JoinModel
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public contentsummary Contentsummary { get; set; }
    public courselist Courselist { get; set; }
    public courselist2019 Courselist2019 { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
 public ActionResult Index( )
        {

    var searchResults = (from a in db.courselist
                 join b in db.coursesummary on
                                new { subject=a.subject, catalog=a.catalog    } equals
                                 new { subject=b.Subject,   catalog=b.Catalogno } into ab
                                 where a.active ==true
                                 from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                 select new JoinModel
                                 {
                                     Courselist = a,
                                     Contentsummary = b


                                 }).ToList();
return View(searchResults);
}
```

I tried to change the query

```
var searchResults = (from a in db.courselist
                 join b in db.coursesummary on
                                new { subject=a.subject, catalog=a.catalog } equals
                                 new { subject=b.Subject, catalog=b.Catalogno } into ab
                                 where a.active ==true
                                 from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                 //select new JoinModel
                                  select new
                                 {
                                     Courselist = a,
                                     Contentsummary = b


                                 }).ToList()
                                 .Select(x=>new JoinModel(){Courselist=x.a, Contentsummary=x.b});
```

Comment: CourseDataModel.cs is missing `}` after the `courselist` setter

Comment: Is that your first query working properly and the second query throwing exception? Also I want to know if `JoinModel` is an entity class instead of DTO.

Comment: The JoinModel is DTO. The first query works before I added the new table courselist2019 into the JoinModel.cs. Now I created a JoinModel2 for courselist2019 but it still returns the same error.

Comment: I searched online solutions for the same error message and created the second query but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my CourseDataModel.cs file had extra line of code generated by the system. I commented it out and it works now :

```
//public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<course.Models.JoinModel2019> JoinModel2019 { get; set; }
```